# Shapefile error in QGIS, rivers of a map

Tags: qgis, shapefile, error, mapping

I am a beginner with QGIS. This file was sent to me along with others by my professor. One of them doesn't work. I'm mapping an Australian river catchment (Daly), one of the shapefiles is for the territory and the other one for the rivers contained in the territory. This last one isn't recognized by QGIS.

The message:

> Invalid Data Source: D:\Desktop\Tesis\Para Qgis\Rivers.zip is not a valid or recognized data source.

The files:[image]

Comment: Unzip the file first?

Comment: You can access most archives directly via the *Browser* panel; then just drag'n' drop the *.shp* file into the *Layer* panel.

Comment: The zip file does not contain mandatory Shape Index Format (_.shx_) file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

Comment: Try the solution from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306218/creating-missing-shx-file to restore the shx file.

Comment: Or email the professor and tell them the River_500_Albers shapefile is missing its *shx* file. They may have forgotten to select it when creating the zipfile. No need to fix corrupted data if you have access to the original, uncorrupted data.